# How to detele row and fill-in column in multiple data.frames at once?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have over 10 data.frames with the same columns. First column is filled with "!" and I want to change it into data.frame name. Each data frame have over 7 000 rows. Last row in each data.frame is empty that I want to remove. My goal is to merge the data.frames but preserve the origin of the data in first column.

I have a list of data frame names in temp2, those are also names I want to put into first column of given data frame.

```
    > str(temp2)
     chr [1:13] "bone_marrow" "colon" "duodenum" "esophagus" "liver" "lymph_node" "rectum" ...
```

The first column to be filled in by data.frame name in named "Tissue" `df$Tissue`

I tried to delete last row in each data frame with:

```
    for (i in 1:length(temp2)) assign(temp2[i], temp2[i][-nrow(temp2[i],)])
```

and to fill the first column with data frame name with:

```
    for (i in 1:length(temp2)) paste0(temp2[i], "$Tissue = ", temp2[i])
```

or

```
    for (i in 1:length(temp2)) paste0(temp2[i], "$Tissue") <- temp2[i]
```

the first code (for deleting last rows) returns:

```
Error in nrow(temp2[i], ) : unused argument (alist())
```

the second code is silent but does nothing,
the last one returns:

```
Error in paste0(temp2[i], "$Tissue") <- temp2[i] : 
could not find function "paste0<-"
```

and the final goal to merge all the data frames into one with `rbind` or `merge`

```
    for (i in 1:length(temp2)) allDF = rbind(temp2[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your data frames are df1, df2, df3.

First, you can combine them into a list:

```
dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Then you can create new columns for each of them and strip the last row of each data frame (the head() function with argument -1 removes the last row):

```
dflist2 <- lapply(1:NROW(dflist), 
    function(i) {dflist[[i]]$Tissue <- temp2[i]; 
                 head(dflist[[i]], -1)}
    )
```

And, finally, you can bind them into one big dataframe:

```
mydf <- do.call(rbind, dflist2)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Is there a possibility to use `temp2` for `dflist <- list(temp2)`. Right now I had to manually type `df1, df2, df3, ...`. Thanks again!

Comment: You could do dflist <- lapply(temp2, get)

Comment: Great! Thats what I was looking for!

Comment: If this meets your requirements, please upvote and accept answer.

Comment: I've got less than 15 reputation to have my votes displayed.